# Issue with Tailwind CSS not reflecting changes in React project

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

I'm currently working on a React project and trying to integrate Tailwind CSS for styling. However, I'm facing an issue where the changes I make in my CSS files are not being reflected on the web application.

I've followed the installation steps for Tailwind CSS and made sure the required dependencies are installed in my project. I've also included the necessary classes in my JSX components as per the documentation.

Despite these efforts, the styles defined in my CSS files are not being applied to the web app when I run `npm start`.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Installed Tailwind CSS and its dependencies.
2. Created and linked my CSS files to my React components.
3. Used Tailwind CSS classes in my JSX components.

Here's an example of my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.4",
    "postcss": "^8.4.12",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23"
  }
}


Its not reflecting any of the properties 

    Created a new React app using Create React App.
    Installed necessary dependencies, including Tailwind CSS, using the npm install command.
    Configured Tailwind CSS by creating a tailwind.css file with appropriate imports.
    Used Tailwind CSS classes in React components for styling.
    Ensured that the tailwind.config.js file was present with default configuration.
    Checked for any possible errors or warnings in the console.
    Verified that the dependencies in package.json were correctly set.

Despite these steps, the issue persisted where the changes made in the CSS files were not being reflected in the web application when running npm start.
```

Comment: You need a config file, do you have it in place? Also, you need to set up tailwind directives. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

Comment: yes I have the config file also I made new project with all the basic code of setup but still the same issue

Comment: maybe your `tailwind.css` file is not linked in your component.

Comment: I think have but can you tell me how can I recheck it I mean which part I should check

Comment: How are you using the classes? In `className` directly, or using them dynamically? Tailwind does not recognize the classes correctly if not used in `className`.

Comment: const BellIcon = () => <FaRegBell size='24' className='top-navigation-icon' />;

Comment: Consider upgrading `react-scripts` to v5 or higher. Tailwind does not work with anything lower. Also as per [the recommendations in their install guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app), consider using using Vite, Parcel, Next.js, or Remix instead of Create React App.